# How to make a table with automatic column widths without using HTML table?

Tags: html, css, html-table, grid-layout

I have a big table I'm trying to add some hover effects to and finding that CSS tables are relatively inflexible, so I'd like to try to implement some other way (see background below).

I'm thinking CSS grid might work. How can I make a CSS table using CSS grid? I need the columns widths to adjust automatically (and of course be synced between rows), as they do with a regular CSS table, and (I think) I need each row to be a parent element to its cells, as in tables.

I read [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) that the level 2 specifications of CSS grid incorporate a subgrid, but I've been unable to find an example of using subgrid to duplicate basic table functionality. It seems most browsers don't yet implement subgrid, so `display: contents` might be an alternative.

**Background in case you need it**: I'm trying to implement a sort of action-bar hover-overlay, as in Gmail: when you hover the cursor over a row/email, an overlay appears on the right side of the row with various actions you can perform on the row/email, such as Move to folder, Delete. Gmail displays the table rows as flex boxes to make this possible, but that means the column widths have to be set "by hand." In my case I have a massive table of various data and setting column widths by hand isn't feasible.

**UPDATE**: what does it look like? It's an ordinary table with rows and columns. You have certainly seen such things before. I'm asking a general question and the particulars of the table are irrelevant.

Here is a screen shot from Gmail, fwiw:

[image: screenshot from mail showing action overlay on one row]

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: prove your question so that it will be easy

Comment: @mplungjan, thanks. I did some research--for three days. And I've asked questions here before. My previous attempts would not be helpful, since they involved flexbox, which isn't feasible for the reason mentioned.

Comment: @Yousaf, not sure what you're asking. It's a table with rows and columns. The contents vary from time to time and shouldn't matter in any case. Perhaps you could clarify?

Comment: @Gad, what do you mean by "prove"?

Comment: @JohnK It is very hard to guess what you mean. Could you post some HTML example and some images of how you expect it to look?

Comment: what i mean is what should be the layout of the table? It would be helpful if you post some image or html example of the table you want to create using css grid.

Comment: i mean your question is somehow not understandable and complicated

Comment: That Gmail thingy is totally possible even inside a normal html `<table>`

Comment: @JonesJoseph, then if you could put that in answer, I'd be most grateful!

Comment: is [this](https://jsbin.com/nazahijojo/1/edit?css,output) what you want?

Comment: @Yousaf, close. But it looks like the number and width of the columns are set "by hand," in this case hardcoded in the CSS.

Comment: check now [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/sowakodevi/1/edit?css,output)

Comment: @Yousaf, that's pretty good. I added a middle column, and put a `position: absolute`, etc. on the last column (`relative` on the row) to make it hover over the row, and it looks great. Why not make that an answer?

Comment: added my code as an answer, also added absolute position on the last column.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the last cell of each row to hold the action icons. Then display them on `tr:hover`

```css
  * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI'
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td,
table th {
  padding: .5em 1em;
  text-align: left;
}

table th {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
}

table tr td:last-child {
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.row-action {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  right: 1em;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
}

tr:hover .row-action {
  display: block;
}

i:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 1em;
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.12.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Name
      </th>
      <th>
        Address
      </th>
      <th>
        Contact
      </th>
      <th>
        Name
      </th>
      <th>
        Address
      </th>
      <th>
        Contact
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Name
      </td>
      <td>
        Address
      </td>
      <td>
        Contact
      </td>
      <td>
        Name
      </td>
      <td>
        Address
      </td>
      <td>
        Contact
        <span class="row-action">
              <i class="fas fa-reply"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-reply-all"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-comment-dots"></i>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        Name
      </td>
      <td>
        Address
      </td>
      <td>
        Contact
      </td>
      <td>
        Name
      </td>
      <td>
        Address
      </td>
      <td>
        Contact
        <span class="row-action">
        <i class="fas fa-reply"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-reply-all"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-comment-dots"></i>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is helpful. I've seen solutions like this elsewhere, but wasn't able to get them to work for some reason; I'll have to look more deeply into my issues.

Comment: @JohnK Which part of the other solution didnt work?  Maybe you can post the code you tried. Could be fixed

Comment: There's some weirdness here with the overlay column. Even when it is positioned absolutely, it still takes up space in the row. (I think that's why the horizontal positioning on that overlay is difficult.) The upshot is that this doesn't work with the overlay column placed to the left of any other column, but only as the last column.

Comment: thats right.. position relative/absolute doesnt really work on `<tr>` so we would have to make do with the last column... it wont work even if the table goes beyond the viewport

Answer (score 1):

Using css grid's `repeat` function, you can create columns automatically depending on the content inside the grid. I have added absolute position on last column so that it overlaps the row.

```css
.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, max-content));
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 10px;
  grid-gap: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
}

.row span.action {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fff;
}

i {
  padding: 0 3px;
}

.row:hover span.action {
  display: initial;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.0-2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <span>Code Academy</span>
    <span>Save your spot to learn from home today. Save your spot to learn from home today</span>
    <span class="action">
        <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
        <i class="far fa-envelope-open"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-reply"></i>
      </span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span>Code Academy</span>
    <span>Save your spot to learn from home today. Save your spot to learn from home today</span>
    <span class="action">
        <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
        <i class="far fa-envelope-open"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-reply"></i>
      </span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span>Code Academy</span>
    <span>Save your spot to learn from home today. Save your spot to learn from home today</span>
    <span class="action">
        <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
        <i class="far fa-envelope-open"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-reply"></i>
      </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks promising. But I notice that if I swap the visible columns, say on the third row, the column widths don't adjust to be consistent across rows. Is there any way to fix this so the column widths work as with tables?

Comment: you can change `minmax(100px, max-content)` to `minmax(100px, 1fr)`. Doing this will make all the columns of equal width

Comment: Thanks, @Yousaf. Unfortunately all columns with equal widths isn't what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Just to show how the `<table>` can be used in the "flex" way. Ofcourse you may change the table and table related elements in a `<div class="..">` element. Use in both solutions the table structure.

The css is cross browser and responsive for smartphone, tablet, desktop and other devices.

```
<div class="tbl">   or   <div class="tbl">
  <table>                  <div class="table">
    <tr>                     <div class="tr">
      ...                      ...
    </tr>                    </div>
  </table>                 </div>
</div>                   </div>
```

with css

```
.tbl {
  max-width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.tbl * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}
table, .table {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: relative;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: transparent;
}
thead, tbody, tfoot, .thead, .tbody, .tfoot {
  display: block;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
tr, .tr {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  position: relative;
}
th, td, .th, .td {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  flex: 0 0 25%;  /* column width */
  max-width: 25%; /* column width */
  white-space: normal;
  word-break: break-all; /* for very long words */
}
/* below for smartphone */
@media (max-width: 767.9px) {
  table, .table {
    border: 0;
    overflow-x: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
  }
}
/* below some styling */
table, .table {
  border-top: 1px solid silver;
  border-left: 1px solid silver;
}
th, td, .th, .td {
  border-right: 1px solid silver;
  border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
}
```

**Example** below you'll find the extra css for a table with 3 flex columns where each column has a different width.

Note that the sum of all columns is 100%

```
tr th:nth-child(1), tr td:nth-child(1) {
  flex: 0 0 22%;
  max-width: 22%;
}
tr th:nth-child(2), tr td:nth-child(2) {
  flex: 0 0 46%;
  max-width: 46%;
}
tr th:nth-child(3), tr td:nth-child(3) {
  flex: 0 0 32%;
  max-width: 32%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But how do I get the column widths to sync between rows automatically?

Comment: Edited the example for flex columns.

Comment: Thanks. For my table(s), the number and ordering of the columns can be changed by the user, so the widths need to be adjusted automatically, not by hand.

Comment: OK. For other people who like to try this css, it is cross browser and responsive for smartphone, tablet, desktop and other devices.